# Switch Rating for 50W LEDS

Tags: led, switches

I plan to have three 50 watt, 12V LEDS, 3750mA wired in parallel.  I would like to have an individual switch for each light.

What amp rating switch would I need for each light.  I wasn't sure if I need to factor the Ah of the battery or just account for the 3750mA the light demands (or is it the combined amps of all lights?) Sorry, learning here obviously.

Resistors aside, I would assume I would run the neutral from the LED to the battery and interrupt the Hot wire with the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each switch is supplying one string, you would just need to size the switch for the individual string - 3.75A.  Just make sure you are using a switch with a DC current rating of 3.75 or more; going off an AC rating alone is risky.

Yes, ground to the battery and switch on the positive supply line is fine.

You would need a separate resistor for each string but we can't speak to its size without knowing about the battery voltage.  However, if you're using a battery, the voltage will vary as it discharges and you're trying to run a pretty high powered system so a simple (high power) resistor is probably not the best choice.

Comment: I want to run off a 12v battery....I’m learning about constant current drivers but unable to find one that matches my setup

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the LEDs and the battery?  The 50W, 12V rating makes me suspect that there might be a driver already in the LED module.

Comment: I don’t despite asking...cheaper COBs from China. Would there be a visual indicator of a driver on the chip

Comment: There would be some sort of chip or small circuit that is obviously not a light-emitting component.

Comment: Not seeing anything :( it will be used sparingly so I suppose I will have to deal with voltage issues